# CSS styling for Mono C#

Tags: c#, css, mono, gtk, xamarin

I develop a c# mono launcher via Xamarin Studio. Is there a way to use CSS for the style of the UI components? I found this: [GtkCSSProvider](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.0/GtkCssProvider.html), but it looks like that its only for C++.
Maybe there is a other way to use CSS or other style methods for the UI components.
Thanks for every help.

Greetings Chryb

Answer (score 2):

I think Pixate tries to do this.

https://github.com/Pixate/MonoTouch-Pixate

No idea how good it is though.

Comment: I think it is only for iOS developing not for Desktop Apps.

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin Forms 3.0, CSS is introduced:

Usage: https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/css/

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <StyleSheet Source="/Assets/styles.css" />
</ContentPage.Resources>
```